# Flexbox wont take width of children when child has nested image with min-height:100%

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to get a container to expand to the width of the children. One of the children is div containing an image with min-height=100%. Idea being the image will scale to the height of the container and the container will expand its width accordingly.

What's happening instead is the image scales to the correct height but its having no effect on the width.

Below is a minimal demo demonstrating the issue (you will need to expand to full screen to see the issue clearly). How can I configure this demo so the image gets the full height of the container and also expands the container width to fit it and the other elements?

I've tried many things but can't seem to get it to work. Is this possible with flexbox? Thanks!

```css
.wrapper {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.sidebar {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction:row;
  background-color:red;
  
  padding-right: 50px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.sidebar-wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.image-wrapper {
    display:flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.image-wrapper img {
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:auto;
  object-fit:contain;
}


.info-wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.info-wrapper span {
  line-height:90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://c0.wallpaperflare.com/preview/396/656/54/welsh-corgi-pembroke-puppies-cute-small-dog-thumbnail.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class="info-wrapper">
        <span> Test1 </span>
        <span> Test2 </span>
        <span> Test3 </span>
        <span> Test4 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: min-width: 0; to image-wrapper and max-width:100% to img ?

Comment: thanks for the response! Just tried this out but unfortunately now the image doesn't take the full height of the container [picture](https://i.imgur.com/aU5gOZz.png)

Comment: try cover instead of contain in object-fit

Comment: this crops the image, I'm trying to achieve this without cutting the image off.